# macOS Sierra: Selecting from Quick Look

Tags: macos, quicklook

The following trick is supposed to enable selecting from a Quick Look preview:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection -bool TRUE
```

… and then relaunch Finder.

In the past it worked for me, but not longer.

Is this broken in Sierra?

Comment: That method broke [as of El Capitan](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205574/copy-text-from-quick-look-in-el-capitan), as a matter of fact. There have been numerous suggestions as to how to get this functionality back, and none that I've found have worked.